# fprintf() issues utf-8 linux

Tags: c, linux, utf-8, printf

Ok, I got to print UTF-8 encoded chars to terminal. But printing to file is not working like i expected. Using wchar.h and locale.h as such:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

    wint_t index = 0;

    FILE* fpinout = fopen("UTF-8.txt","w");
    for(index = 0; index < 0x200; index++){
        printf("%i:\t%lc\n", index, index); //works fine, prints utf-8 chars to terminal
        fprintf(fpinout,"%i\t%lc", index, index); //does not work, output is wierd
    }
    fclose(fpinout);
}
```

I tried to use index there both as wint_t and wchar_t.
My UTF-8.txt file looks like this:

```
र㄀ĉल㌂̉ऴ㔄ԉश㜆܉स㤈उ〱ਉㄱଉ㈱ఉ㌱ഉ㐱ฉ㔱༉㘱ဉ㜱ᄉ㠱ሉ㤱ጉ〲ᐉㄲᔉ㈲ᘉ㌲ᜉ㐲᠉㔲ᤉ㘲ᨉ㜲ᬉ㠲ᰉ㤲ᴉ〳ḉㄳἉ㈳ ㌳℉㐳∉㔳⌉㘳␉㜳
┉㠳☉㤳✉〴⠉ㄴ⤉㈴⨉㌴⬉㐴Ⰹ㔴ⴉ㘴⸉㜴⼉㠴〉㤴ㄉ〵㈉ㄵ㌉㈵㐉㌵㔉㐵㘉㔵㜉㘵㠉㜵㤉㠵㨉㤵㬉〶㰉ㄶ㴉㈶㸉㌶㼉㐶䀉㔶䄉㘶䈉
㜶䌉㠶䐉㤶䔉〷䘉ㄷ䜉㈷䠉㌷䤉㐷䨉㔷䬉㘷䰉㜷䴉㠷三㤷伉〸倉ㄸ儉㈸刉㌸匉㐸吉㔸唉㘸嘉㜸圉㠸堉㤸変〹娉ㄹ嬉㈹尉㌹崉㐹帉
㔹弉㘹怉㜹愉㠹戉㤹按〱रㅤ㄰攉〱लㅦ㌰有〱ऴㅨ㔰椉〱शㅪ㜰欉〱सㅬ㤰洉ㄱरㅮㄱ漉ㄱलㅰ㌱焉ㄱऴㅲ㔱猉ㄱशㅴ㜱甉ㄱसㅶ㤱眉
㈱रㅸㄲ礉㈱लㅺ㌲笉㈱ऴㅼ㔲紉㈱शㅾ㜲缉㈱स胂㈱ह臂㌱र苂㌱ऱ菂㌱ल蓂㌱ळ藂㌱ऴ蛂㌱व蟂㌱श裂㌱ष观㌱स諂㌱ह诂㐱र賂㐱ऱ跂㐱ल軂㐱
ळ迂㐱ऴ郂㐱व釂㐱श鋂㐱ष鏂㐱स铂㐱ह闂㔱र雂㔱ऱ韂㔱ल飂㔱ळ駂㔱ऴ髂㔱व鯂㔱श鳂㔱ष鷂㔱स黂㔱ह鿂㘱रꃂ㘱ऱꇂ㘱लꋂ㘱ळꏂ㘱ऴ꓂
㘱वꗂ㘱शꛂ㘱षꟂ㘱सꣂ㘱ह꧂㜱रꫂ㜱ऱꯂ㜱ल곂㜱ळ귂㜱ऴ껂㜱व꿂㜱श냂㜱ष뇂㜱स닂㜱ह돂㠱र듂㠱ऱ뗂㠱ल뛂㠱ळ럂㠱ऴ룂㠱व맂㠱श뫂
㠱ष믂㠱स볂㠱ह뷂㤱र뻂㤱ऱ뿂㤱ल胃㤱ळ臃㤱ऴ苃㤱व菃㤱श蓃㤱ष藃㤱स蛃㤱ह蟃〲र裃〲ऱ觃〲ल諃〲ळ诃〲ऴ賃〲व跃〲श軃〲ष迃〲स郃〲ह
釃ㄲर鋃ㄲऱ鏃ㄲल铃ㄲळ闃ㄲऴ雃ㄲव韃ㄲश飃ㄲष駃ㄲस髃ㄲह鯃㈲र鳃㈲ऱ鷃㈲ल黃㈲ळ鿃㈲ऴꃃ㈲वꇃ㈲शꋃ㈲षꏃ㈲स꓃㈲हꗃ㌲रꛃ㌲ऱꟃ㌲
लꣃ㌲ळ꧃㌲ऴ꫃㌲वꯃ㌲श곃㌲ष귃㌲स껃㌲ह꿃㐲र냃㐲ऱ뇃㐲ल닃㐲ळ돃㐲ऴ듃㐲व뗃㐲श뛃㐲ष럃㐲स룃㐲ह맃㔲र뫃㔲ऱ믃㔲ल볃㔲ळ뷃㔲ऴ뻃
㔲व뿃
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: opening the file in binary mode might help.. `fopen("UTF-8.txt","wb");`

Comment: Your terminal and your file viewer are using different decodings.  Same data is going to `stdout` and "UTF-8.txt", but your are not reading them the same way.

Comment: @chux I'm using gedit as text editor/viewer, and have been able to open file in UTF-8 formating by this process:
open gedit > open > in character encoding choose utf-8 > openfile

by doing this i get the right output. But i cant do this by default.
I can also confirm it is possible to write a text file and read from it without trouble, outputing to terminal the right characters.

Comment: You have posted code and "weird" output.  Suggest posting input and/or expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This way you write UTF32 by fact. Opening file in binary mode won't help. it will remain UTF32LE.

You should use transformation to UTF8 encoding. Either use ICU library or wctomb / wctombs / wclen c functions ( http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wctomb.3.html ). be aware that wctomb* functions usually are locale dependent (often won't work correctly with Japanese if you have Greek locale)

Comment: Could you expand a little on your answer?

Comment: Surely but I would want to know what is not clear for you. UTF-8 is variable length encoding that is each symbol can take starting from 1 (for ASCII) up to 4 bytes (in practical use) and 6 in theory. Terminal is just clever enough by reason it is run in UTF8 mode, files are usual files, they contain what you provided and form UTF-8 point of view you provided is what you practically see when open the file in the editor. wikipedia article is good IMHO http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: I would like to know how one would go about using ICU libraries for C/C++ ,specifically in Ubuntu Trusty, to achieve this result. I am using C::B IDE.
I've found this tutorial about building and installing ICU:http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/icu.html

But what now?

Comment: use it as all other libraries. if you don't know how I think google will help. basically you have to specify include path and library path + library, like options to compiler -I /my_icu/header/path -L my_place_to_icu_library -licu. I personally don't use ubuntu (btw I recoment gentoo) but i suspect that you have already icu in ubuntu, and even possible that you have it already with headers. Then trivial gcc my_program.c -licu should help.